# How to determine the transition probability in Sequential Importance Sampling (SIS) for Particle Filter

Tags: markov-chains, bayesian, control-theory, monte-carlo

Given a state-space model

\begin{align}
x_k &= f_k(x_{k-1}, v_{k-1}),\\
z_k &= h_k(x_k, w_k),
\end{align}

where $x_k \in {\mathbb R}^{n}$ and $y_k \in {\mathbb R}^{m}$ are the system state and system output in time $k \in \overline{\mathbb Z}_+$. $v_{k-1} \in {\mathbb R}^{p}$ and $w_k \in {\mathbb R}^{q}$ are white noises. $f_k:{\mathbb R}^{n+p} \to {\mathbb R}^{n}$ and $h_k:{\mathbb R}^{n+q} \to {\mathbb R}^{m}$ are nonlinear functions.

Then, the ISI method can be used to approximate the posterior $p(x_k|z_k,\ldots,z_1)$. However, it needs the transition probability $p(x_k|x_{k-1})$. In many textbooks, this probability is assumed to be given, but how to derive it from the above two highly nonlinear equations in the state-space model? Thanks very much!

Comment: I refer you to these two links. It may help you. [first link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201545/likelihood-calculation-in-particle-filtering) [second link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263838/sampling-from-likelihood-likelihood-particle-filter)

Comment: @Alireza Thanks very much for your help!